# LOAD DATA INFILE - mysql/php script not functioning as it should

Tags: php, mysql, database, load-data-infile

Trying to use 'LOAD DATA INFILE' in order to populate a database table from a CSV(10k records) but at the moment it does nothing.

No error, no data being input and I have no idea what is wrong with it so any help is appreciated!

```
My code (-CSS and DBconnect):


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded
   successfully." . "</h1>";
}

$temp_file = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']; 
$origin_file = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$target_file = 'uploads/'.$origin_file;
move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $target_file);
$file_name = $target_file;

$query = <<<eof
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file_name'
 INTO TABLE importing
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(text,number)
IGNORE 1 LINES
eof;

mysql_query($query);


print "Import done";

mysql_close(); 
//view upload form
}else {

print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";

print "File name to import:<br />\n";

print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Note

Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

To see what error your code outputs change

```
mysql_query($query);
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Then [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) will output the error instead of just nothing ...

As pointed out by [@Lèsemajesté](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370940/lese-majeste) - `move_uploaded_file()` also returns a `boolean` which you should check is `true` :

> Returns TRUE on success.
>
> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.
>
> If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

[Full docs for `move_uploaded_file()` here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: To be safe, he should probably do the same with `move_uploaded_file()` as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go convert it to MySQLi now :)

turned out that it was "(text,number)" causing the problem in my query